# How to animate reorder with React Native FlatList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have some UI that looks like this:

[image]

These list items can be: (1) added, (2) deleted, (3) reordered.

The reordering is *not* drag and drop, but happens when clicking the check/empty circle icons - the checked items always stay at the top of the list.

There are many examples of animating adding/removing items from lists in React Native ([here's one such example](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-animate-the-items-of-a-react-native-flatlist-32c8cbf7ea3d)).

But how can I animate the ordering of a list? Specifically in my case, it would be two list items swapping position.

I have seen [react-native-sortable-list](https://github.com/gitim/react-native-sortable-list) and a few other open source projects, but I think this is probably overkill as I *do not* need drag and drop. Also, I am already hooking into some FlatList events like `onLayout`, `onContentSizeChange`, and `onScroll`, so I would prefer a solution that allows me to animate the children of a FlatList directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flatlist is sorted in order of the array that you feed it through the `data` prop. Whether you are using component-level state (i.e. `this.state` ) or redux to manage your state, you can reorder the array of elements and it should rerender in that order. For example, one implementation may be:

```
const checkedData = [...this.state.data].filter(item => item.checked === true);
const uncheckedData = [...this.state.data].filter(item => item.checked !== true);
const sortedData = checkData.concat(uncheckedData);
this.setState({ data: sortedData });
```

The javascript filter function should preserve original sort order of the subset.

To animate it, you can then look into [`LayoutAnimation`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html#docsNav) in react native. It will apply an animation type to every change in your view between renders.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add onto Nth.gol 's answer which helped me solve the same issue.

To animate the list in simple way:

1. Update the state of the list to the new state you wish to animate to
2. Add this line above the state update:

   `LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);`
3. To make sure the animation also works on Andriod add this code outside of your constructor:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android' && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}
```

Note: You will need to import `LayoutAnimation` && `UIManager` from `react-native`

There are many options for configuring the duration & type of animation, but this is a nice & simple working solution. You can read more about the configuration options here: [LayoutAnimation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation)